# Plotting the modular surface of a complex function

Tags: plotting, complex

Tristan Needham stated in the introduction to Visual Complex Analysis that he used Mathematica to create the majority of graphs in his book. I'm trying to recreate the graph he made for figure[14] of this example.

I've attempted to use the [Im[z]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Im.html) function from the documentation but I haven't found many intuitive examples and was wondering if I could be pointed in the right direction as how to use it correctly. I haven't taken a complex analysis course yet, this is me reading ahead so I may just not have the knowledge to do what I'm asking yet.

Here is the example I speak of from earlier from Visual Complex Analysis:
[image]

Comment: Try `Plot3D[Log[Abs[1/(1 + (x + I y)^2)]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Lighting -> "Neutral", PlotStyle -> White]` and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says on page 66 of the book you are quoting, figure[14] is the *modular surface* of $h(z)$. That concept was defined of page 56. To reproduce figure[14], you simply have to make a 3D plot of the modular surface and adjust it's display form by giving the proper options. The following should get you going.

```
h[x_, y_] := With[{z = x + I y}, Abs[1/(1 + z^2)]]
Plot3D[h[x, y], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image: plot]